# Bounds on quantiles of the minimum of summations of (possibly dependent) random variables

Tags: random-variable, quantiles, copula, probability-inequalities, bounds

Suppose I have $2N$ continuous random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_N, Y_1, \ldots, Y_N$ and that I can evaluate the quantiles of the respective distributions. Given a value $w \in [0, 1]$ I would like to upper bound the $w$-quantile of $\min\left\{X_1 + Y_1, \ldots, X_N + Y_N\right\}$, $Q^w_{\min\left\{\ldots\right\}}$.

For the individual summations, I know that I assume the minimum copula $C^-(u, v) = \max\left\{u+v-1, 0\right\}$ and use the Fréchet-Hoeffding bounds to derive (as done by [Wiiliamson and Downs](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P5.pdf))
$$Q^{w}_{X+Y} \le \inf\limits_{u \in [w,1]} \left\{Q^{u}_{X} + Q^{1 - u + w}_{Y} \right\}.$$
With that I can use the following bound $$Q^w_{\min\left\{\ldots\right\}} \leq \min\left\{Q^{w}_{X_1+Y_1}, \ldots, Q^{w}_{X_N+Y_N}\right\},$$
however such bound seems to be rather loose as illustrated by the figure below.

[image]

Is it somehow possible to do better than that? I would expect that evaluating the individual sum-quantiles at some lower value than $w$ (not necessarily equal for all operands) should be possible.

Would it be if the individual summations were independent (i.e. for each $(i, j) \in [1, N]^2$ such that $i \neq j$, $X_i + Y_i$ and $X_j + Y_j$ were independent)?